# Media queries and base font-size

Tags: css, media-queries

hey guys can anyone assist on this . I a m designing using mobile first website that has 14px font-size for mobile, 16 for tablet and 18 for desktop which I want to converted to em. My question is in the media queries should I redefine the base font for each type of screen or just use the 14px base font and convert to em?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: That's pretty much up to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can try viewport sized typography. It's great if you want responsive fonts. CSS3 has some new values for sizing things relative to the current viewport size: vw, vh, and vmin

For example:

```
1vw = 1% of viewport width
1vh = 1% of viewport height
1vmin = 1vw or 1vh, whichever is smaller
1vmax = 1vw or 1vh, whichever is larger
```

Usage:

```
h1 {
  font-size: 5.9vw;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 3.0vh;
}
p {
  font-size: 2vmin;
}
```

more on this link:
https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/

Comment: Is not it possible using ems?

Comment: Em is relative to parent, vw is relative to viewport width. You can achieve everything you want with ems but it's easier with vw. 16px is 1.11vw. 14px is 0.97vw. Here is calculator http://emilolsson.com/tools/vw-unit-calc-an-online-responsive-css-font-size-calculator/. Try it out.

Comment: My question is when I am working with media query, should put in each breakpoint the default font size for that type of device. for instance is it ok to do this @media all and (min-width: @mobileBreakpoint)

{

body{ 
font-size: 18px;
}


#header { 
  
  .title{ font-size: 2.66em;   // default font in px is 18px 
  
  
  }
   
   
  .subtitle{
   
   font-size: 1.66em;  //    30px/18px
   line-height: 1.84em; // 33px/18px;
   }
   
   .tag{
    font-size: 0.72em;  // 13px/18px
 
   }
  }
  
#body{
 
 .section-headline{

font-size: 2em;
line-height: 2.33em ;


}

Comment: If you are going to do media query for every screen then you can do it with px, pt, em, it doesn't matter. You will manually adjust font size for every screen. We use responsive font sizes like vw and em because we want to define them only once and they will automatically adjust on all screens. No media queries are needed. Define them once and that's it.

Comment: @amad4biz no problem, what did you use at the end? will you accept the answer?

Comment: @amad4biz actually  the best way is using em 
why? ... cause its related to font size of users browser font-size and for accessibility reasons em is best way to do that